# "nginx: [emerg] "events" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf:1" Error in nginX

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make reverse load balancer proxy server with nginX.

I created express server at `106.10.**.***:3000` and `106.10.**.***:4000`

When I ran `systemctl start nginx.service` it returned error like

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@airbnb-api:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# systemctl start nginx.service
```

so I tried systemctl status nginx.service which is on below

```
events { }

http {
    upstream backend {
        server 106.10.**.***:3000;
        server 106.10.**.***:4000;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}
```

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-10-29 00:22:20 KST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 3634 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api nginx[3634]: nginx: [emerg] "events" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf:1
Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api nginx[3634]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 29 00:22:20 airbnb-api systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've checked `106.10.**.***:3000` `106.10.**.***:4000` and they worked well.

Noting returned when trying `sudo lsof -i:80`

both code returned to be successful

```
nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf
nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf
```

Comment: `listen 80;` was missing..

Answer (score 0):

You have a config issue with your event directive

> "events" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf:1

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to change the keywords and search out again.